# delete with eager load in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm trying to delete a collection but I want to delete the NFTs related to a collection as well. How do I do this?

‍‍This is my Nft model `Nft.php`

```
class Nft extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,SoftDeletes;

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Collection::class);
    }
}
```

This is my collection model `Collection.php`

```
class Collection extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;
    public function nfts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Nft::class);
    }
}
```

This is my COntroller `CollectionController.php`

```
 public function deleteCollection(int $id):RedirectResponse
    {
        Collection::with('nfts')->find($id)->delete();
        return redirect('/collections');
    }
```

But it did not work!!!
pleas help me!!!!!

Comment: I recommend using an observer. You can read about them in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

At user model:

```
public function collection() {
return $this->belongsTo(Collection::class)->withTrashed(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the observer events are not fired if you use mass delete for example. In the case Collection::with('nfts')->delete(); it might not work.

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Collection extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleting(function ($collection) {
            $collection->nfts()->delete()
        });
    }
}
```